# Conda environments python and atom

Tags: python, conda, atom-editor, environment

I'm pretty new to coding, and am trying to improve the way I'm working. I'm using the anaconda3 distribution of python and do most of my code writing in Atom, then running the code via the command line. I've spent the afternoon reading about virtual environments and am going in circles a bit. My question is this:

Should I be defining a new conda environment (other than the base) for each project I create, as the first line of code for each new project?

Thanks I'm pretty aware this is a very noob question. I've found some good answers around this, but I think I'm missing some key aspects of the problem.

Comment: The reasons why you want to use venv is to avoid dependency clashes. Now coming to your question if you should do this as a first step when you create a new project. I would say no it's fine if you use 1 venv for multiple project's

Comment: Thanks Simon, that makes sense - I guess it will only become a problem later down the line with packages becoming dated etc.?

Comment: yes, that's the whole reasons why you wanna do it. An easy way to avoid those issue you can create a `requirement.txt` on the top level of your project. This includes required packages and versions to run this project. And then later on if needed you can just create a venv for any project and just install the requirements ;)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot - big help!